# FileUploader with custom headers

Tags: angular

I'm using ng2-file-upload to upload files. I need to set a custom header. This is what I have:

```
this.uploader =  new FileUploader({url: this.uploadUrl, itemAlias: 'files', headers: [{name: 'accept', value: 'application/json'}] });
```

when I inspect the headers on the server side

```
Request.Headers["accept"]
```

All I see is `"*/*"`.

How can I set the custom header?

Answer (score 0):

If the header use HTTP header you can use Headers i think.

```
import {Headers} from '@angular/http';

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

this.uploader =  new FileUploader(
   {url: this.uploadUrl, itemAlias: 'files', headers }
);
```

Comment: I still keep getting the "*/*" value.

Comment: can u write request and response header?